# How to configure OAuth2 RestTemplate for spring boot config client

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-oauth2

**How can I configure a spring boot config client microservice to fetch its configuration from an OAuth2 configServer which is @EnableResourceServer ?**

I have one OAuth2 Authorization server (@EnableAuthorizationServer). There is a configServer (@EnableConfigServer) which I have configured to respond only to valid requests authorized by authorization server containing JWT tokens.

There is also a microservice client **APP1** of the config server which needs to fetch its configuration upon startup from the aforementioned config server. Since the server only responds to requests containing valid access tokens (jwt tokens) I tried to inject [OAuth2RestTemplate](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/oauth/apidocs/org/springframework/security/oauth2/client/OAuth2RestTemplate.html)  into [ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/blob/master/spring-cloud-config-client/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/config/client/ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator.java) so that my config client (APP1) could fetch its config.

In order to do that I tried the partial solution which was discussed [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/issues/177).

This is my OAuth2 ready RestTemplate that I want to inject

```
@Configuration
public class OAuthConfig {

@Bean
public OAuth2RestTemplate oauth2RestTemplate(OAuth2ClientContext oauth2ClientContext,
        OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails details) {
    return new OAuth2RestTemplate(details, oauth2ClientContext);
}}
```

and this is my custom property locator

```
public class CustomConfigServicePropertySourceLocator {

@Autowired
private ConfigurableEnvironment environment;
@Autowired
private RestTemplate restTemplate;

@Bean
public ConfigClientProperties configClientProperties() {
    ConfigClientProperties client = new ConfigClientProperties(this.environment);
    client.setEnabled(false);
    return client;
}

@Bean
@Primary
public ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator configServicePropertySourceLocator() {
    ConfigClientProperties clientProperties = configClientProperties();
    ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator configServicePropertySourceLocator = new ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator(
            clientProperties);
    configServicePropertySourceLocator.setRestTemplate(restTemplate);
    return configServicePropertySourceLocator;
}}
```

I Followed the instructions in [Customizing the Bootstrap Configuration](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-commons/multi/multi__spring_cloud_context_application_context_services.html#_customizing_the_bootstrap_configuration)

I created a META_INF > spring.factories file containing

org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapConfiguration=com.company.mcapp.CustomConfigServicePropertySourceLocator

By debugging I can see that this custom locator will get called but my **APP1** is failing to contact config server to fetch the configurations.

In **initialize** method of [PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-commons/blob/master/spring-cloud-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/bootstrap/config/PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration.java) (below) I can see that the propertySourceLocators does not contain my CustomConfigServicePropertySourceLocator.

```
@Override
public void initialize(ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext) {
    CompositePropertySource composite = new CompositePropertySource(
            BOOTSTRAP_PROPERTY_SOURCE_NAME);
    AnnotationAwareOrderComparator.sort(this.propertySourceLocators);
    boolean empty = true;
    ConfigurableEnvironment environment = applicationContext.getEnvironment();
    for (PropertySourceLocator locator : this.propertySourceLocators) {
        PropertySource<?> source = null;
        source = locator.locate(environment);
        if (source == null) {
            continue;
        }
        logger.info("Located property source: " + source);
        composite.addPropertySource(source);
        empty = false;
    }
    .
    .
    .
```

**UPDATE:** The issue was a silly mistake That I made. Instead of creating META-INF I created META**_**INF.

Comment: Hi I have the similar requirement and tried this way which didn't seem to work. Can you please help me with more details regarding your package structure and config details? My question is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75323044/spring-cloud-config-oauth2-endpoint