# Spring Cloud Config OAuth2 EndPoint

Tags: spring, oauth-2.0, spring-cloud-config

We have a spring cloud config service which is secured with OAuth2.

In another service, we are configuring this service with spring.config.import: {cloud-cfg-svc-uri}

Since the config service requires Bearer token, I need to make a call to the token provider service and then use that token to call the cloud config service

Is this feasible? Any pointers for help please?

Comment: Did you figure this out?